# how to define versioning in OpenApi3 schema

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

hi I am looking for a way to define versioning via OpenApi3 schema, in OpenApi2 you had the **basePath** parameter which looks not present anymore in OpenApi3.

I am using SpringBoot and we are generating endpoints from the schema with the generator. I would like to add the version parameter somewhere globally to have the endpoints url like www.server.com/v1/endpoint....

What is the best/preferred way to do this in OpenApi3 schema?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI 3.0, the base path is part of the [API server URL](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

servers:
  - url: 'https://api.example.com/v1'
```

Comment: yes but this is only informative, it doensn't generate the endpoints to be present on path /v1/endpoint .... but the controllers are still generated with /endpint path

Comment: Open a ticket at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: I mean i don't know if this is a bug,  if i put servers: url: 'https://api.example.com/v1' the generated endpoints with codgen are without /v1, maybe this is not intended to be.